# Iterate through multiple keys on map

Tags: elixir

I have this code:

```
          {drop_off_lat, _ } = case student_model.drop_off_lat do
            nil -> {0.0, 0}
            value -> {Float.parse(value), 0}
          end

          {drop_off_lng, _ } = case student_model.drop_off_lng do
            nil -> {0.0, 0}
            value -> {Float.parse(value), 0}
          end

          {pick_up_lat, _ } = case student_model.pick_up_lat do
            nil -> {0.0, 0}
            value -> {Float.parse(value), 0}
          end

          {pick_up_lng, _ } = case student_model.pick_up_lng do
            nil -> {0.0, 0}
            value -> {Float.parse(value), 0}
          end
```

for each key (drop_off_lat, drop_off_lng, pick_up_lat, pick_up_lng) I am checking if its nil to replace with 0, otherwise to replace with float parsing of its version.

Although its working, but I feel that the code can be more compact with fewer lines, right?

Comment: Did you mean to do `value -> Float.parse(value)` instead?

Comment: No, I mean to dynamically get the key value, ex: read it from array of keys.. rather than copy and paste each use case above, and only change the key name each time..

Comment: I mean here you'll get `0.0` for `nil` and `{1.2, "foo"}` for "1.2foo" (a float for nil but a tuple for string) and the `, 0` is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` and pattern match its return value:

```
map = %{
  drop_off_lat: nil,
  drop_off_lng: "4.5",
  pick_up_lat: "6.5e2",
  pick_up_lng: nil,
}


[drop_off_lat, drop_off_lng, pick_up_lat, pick_up_lng] =
  for key <- [:drop_off_lat, :drop_off_lng, :pick_up_lat, :pick_up_lng] do
    case map[key] do
      nil -> 0.0
      value -> String.to_float(value)
    end
  end

IO.inspect {drop_off_lat, drop_off_lng, pick_up_lat, pick_up_lng}
```

Output:

```
{0.0, 4.5, 650.0, 0.0}
```

Comment: thanks! but, what does `key <-` actually do? as I am only familiar with left o right arrow as  `->` while the `key <-` arrow is right to left

Comment: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#generators-and-filters explains: `n <- [1, 2, 3, 4]` is a generator. It is literally generating values to be used in the comprehension (i.e. iteration).

Comment: @simo in addition to what GavinBrelstaff said, you can think of that `for` to be equivalent to this map operation: `Enum.map([:drop_off_lat, ...], fn key -> ... end)` but slightly more terse.